# Connecting to Azure IoT Hub without DigiCert Baltimore Root certificate

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-iot-hub

I am using MQTT on my device the Quectel BG95.

I am using th SAS token method of authentication.

I just noticed that if I do not apply the DigiCert Baltimore Root certificate to tcl/SSL connection , I am still able to successfully connect and communication.

Does this seem correct?

Answer (score 1):

To establish a connection between our devices and the IoT Hub we use the MQTT protocol directly and do not rely on the IoT SDKs.

For the TLS connection **it is required that the devices have access to the 'DigiCert Baltimore Root Certificate**'.

We store this certificate on the devices during production, but they may not come online for a long time due to selling/installation delay. It is further important that we have a reasonable time period to update existing devices.

Reference Link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-tls-support

Comment: Yes we are also using MQTT with SAS tokens for authentication.  For some reason, I can connect to the IoT hub without these certificates. And based on this examples, so can they
https://weblogs.asp.net/morteza/how-to-send-mqtt-messages-to-an-azure-iothub-by-mqttfx-client

Am I missing a something?